# Confusion about AlarmManager's CPU lock in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakelock

I am confused about the behavior of `AlarmManager`. Does `AlarmManager` hold the `CPU` lock all the time? In android developer reference site they said

> The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm
>   receiver's onReceive() method is executing

On the other hand RTC_WAKEUP said that

> Alarm time in System.currentTimeMillis() (wall clock time in UTC),
>   which will wake up the device when it goes off

Assume that my device has no other task instead of mine. `CPU` can go to sleep after completing my job. Then what will happen in following situation?

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi);
//pi is pendingIntent.
```

## Situation 1:

```
CPU go to sleep and wake up after 10 minutes. [I will acquire wake lock in intent class]
```

## situation 2:

```
AlarmManager holds CPU for next 10 minutes. It's a repeating task, so AlarmManager holds the CPU all the time until it canceled.
```

## EDIT

Is there any difference between the following pseudo codes

```
acquire_cpu_wakelock();
while(!canceled)
{

    sleep(10); //minutes [update]
    finish_task();

}
release_cpu_wakelock();
```

## and

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi);
```

Comment: You probably need to read the first quoted statement more precisely and literally: "while the alarm receiver's **onReceive() method** is executing" - that won't happen *until* the alarm "fires", and will be concluded when that event method returns.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. What about the RTC_WAKEUP?

Comment: `as long as the alarm receiver's onReceive() method is executing` meaning during the execution of the `onReceive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does AlarmManager hold the CPU lock all the time?

No.

> Then what will happen in following situation?

Your `PendingIntent` will be invoked a 10 minutes after you place the call to `setRepeating()` (except on API Level 19+, in which case repeating alarms are inexact, and so the precise timing is indeterminate).

> AlarmManager holds CPU for next 10 seconds.

No. First, your alarm is for 10 minutes, not 10 seconds. Second, the CPU will be allowed to go into a sleep mode. A different circuit will arrange to wake it back up at the appropriate time.

> Is there any difference between the following pseudo codes

The first will keep the CPU powered on for 10 seconds.

The second will allow the CPU to go into a sleep mode, waking up again after ~10 minutes (where the "~" goes back to my comment about API Level 19+).

Comment: Thanks. It should be 10 minutes, my mistake. I have updated my question

Comment: Now my application is in top position in battery uses list. :( What i am doing is this, trigger AlarmManager in every 1 minutes and send a udp packet of size around 32-64 bytes.

Comment: Uses details: CPU total 5m 30s CPU forground: 3m 45s Keep awake 32m 41s. Is it normal??

Comment: @shantanu: Waking up the device every minute is not going to be especially good for the battery. Waking up a radio every minute is going to be worse, particularly for only sending a packet.